# Qt/Cocoa on MacOS - remove progress bar animation

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, qt, cocoa

in my application there is the QProgressBar I use, but it's not quite illustrating progress of a process, rather it represents a state. Therefore, I want it not to animate on Mac, as it always does. I have no experience with Cocoa, but Qt does not allow me to do that. And therefore I ask some more experienced Cocoa programmers: is it even possible to stop the progress bar animation? I looked for that for quite a while, but I didn't find anything.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could either call setStyle() on the QProgressBar to use a different kind of QStyle instead (i.e. one that doesn't animate); or you could ditch the QProgressBar altogether and use a different widget type entirely (e.g. a QLabel, or just subclass QWidget and implement paintEvent() do draw whatever you want the widget to look like)